npm error react-chartist ошибка
Что не так подскажите что сделать в этой ситуацции
npm install react-chartist --save

npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: template@0.1.0
npm error Found: chartist@1.3.0
npm error node_modules/chartist
npm error   chartist@"^1.3.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer chartist@"^0.10.1" from react-chartist@0.14.4
npm error node_modules/react-chartist
npm error   react-chartist@"*" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error


Отсутствует или какой то конфликт зависимостей. Вы ставили chartist перед react-chartist?
